# Particles with trails in Three.js

Tags: 3d, three.js, webgl

I'm trying create a sphere with a particle that travels between two points along a fixed path.

The path should start and end at the radius of the sphere and at its peak it should be slightly above the sphere, sort of like an airplane flying.

I've gotten a particle to travel along this path, but I want the particle to leave a trail as it travels.

A couple of ideas come to mind.

## Using a line that begins at the start and ends at the particle

A fairly easy way to do it would be to create a line with X segments that begins at the start point and ends at the particles current position going along the particle's path.

However the glow trail would just be stretched which will create a weird effect.
This might be a good plan B though.

## Multiple particles

Another way to do it would be to create multiple particles like in this demo: http://creativejs.com/tutorials/three-js-part-1-make-a-star-field/

I don't think it will look very good though since you need a lot of particles for it to look realistic.

## Using a line along the entire path

A third option would be a to have a line going between the start and end point along the path and update the colour of each vertex.
But since the particle doesn't have discrete positions while the line obviously would have I think I might need a lot of segments for it to look nice.

---

I feel like I've overlooked the obvious solution, any ideas?

Comment: Hello Nicklas A., have you found any solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

This may seem weird and hard, but I believe it could achieve the effect you're after.

Create a ribbon around the sphere, the width of the trail that you would like.
Create another ribbon, same width, also around the sphere, but perpendicular to the previously created ribbon.

Then create particle that would leave the trail as `Particle` or `Sphere` object, depending on your needs.

To simulate the trail, apply semi transparent texture on both ribbons, that would come out of the particle (well, sort of).

To see what I mean, see [this](http://helloenjoy.com/project/lights/) and there you can find [this image](http://helloenjoy.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Lights-Screenshot-4.png).

You can see how they achieved the volumetric look of the light beams, and similarly enough you could create your trail for particle.

Hope this sparks the imagination. :]

Comment: That's an awesome idea! Thanks!